# SWP_NOSIZE doesn't have desired effect

Tags: api, vb6

I have a window that has its ScaleMode set to "Pixel"

When I'm calling the API function "SetWindowPos", I'm passing "SWP_NOSIZE" as an argument:

```
SetWindowPos Me.hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOACTIVATE
```

However, after the API call, the width of my window is 3240 instead of the intended width of 216.

I think this has to do with the fact that 216 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX is 3240.

So I would tend to think that the API call changes the window's ScaleMode.

Does anybody how to avoid it?

Thank you!

Comment: You should shows us: Declaration of function and related constants. What value does the function return?

Comment: the issue is somewhere else, you should post the code where you set the window width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the parameter constant SWP_NOSIZE. The [Windows API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) for SetWindowPos states for SWP_NOSIZE

> Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).

Therfore by applying this constant, you mereley say to ignore the parameters cx and cy. Usually this is the intention if the window should be made the top most window.

Why not just use?

```
Me.Width = 216
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work, and also it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the API function changes the VB6's windows scale mode to twips, no matter what it was before.
I've therefore changed the form to twips instead of pixels, and I changed everything around it (for example by removing "Screen.TwipsPerPixel") accordingly.